# Blackberry Simulator Issues

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

When I run my BlackBerry simulator only the screen appears, without the surrounding area looking like a device. Why doesn't it look like the actual device?
[image: 9800 simulator screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same in my configuration. Use `View-Graphics acceleration-Medium quality` and you'll see the simulated device image.

Answer (score 1):

you can get that by doing this way 
There would be an option **View** in the simulator go and uncheck the **LCD ONLY** option then you can view the full phone .

Comment: the problem was that in View Graphics acceleration was high, but when i reduced it to medium , low or Off the whole phone came, again to check i increased to high quality the phone vanished leaving just the screen, now why would thi s happen?

Comment: http://www.scribd.com/doc/22108891/Blackberry-Simulator-Quick-Start-Guide check once here may be this kind of issue discussed here